# Prime ideal theorem for modular lattices?

Tags: lattice-orders, universal-algebra

There's a well-known theorem for distributive lattices commonly referred to as the "prime ideal theorem:"

> Let $L$ be a distributive lattice, $I$ an ideal of $L$, and $F$ a filter of $L$ such that $I\cap F=\varnothing$. Then there exists a prime ideal $P$ such that $I\subseteq P$ and $P\cap F=\varnothing$.

Is there an analogous theorem for modular lattices? A cursory look through one or two texts and a brief online search seem to indicate that the answer is no, but perhaps I am mistaken.

Does anyone have a counter-example or a reference to an affirmative answer? Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. I haven't worked with lattice ideals enough to understand well ( I only deal with ring ideals) but I'm a bit surprised distributivity matters. A similar theorem holds for rings with identity, although not all rings have distributive lattices of ideals .

Comment: I've just realized that I've been answering all your questions since May! :-)

Comment: And I appreciate it, @PedroSánchezTerraf !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the modular lattice $M_3=\{0,a,b,c,1\}$ where $0,1$ are the minimum and maximum elements, respectively, and consider $I=\{0,c\}$ and $F=\{a,1\}$. There is no (proper) prime ideal containing $I$, and hence none disjoint from $F$. E.g., $I$ is not prime since $a\wedge b=0\in I$ but $a,b\notin I$.

Comment: I wish I had come back to this sooner, because I came up with the same example about an hour ago! Thank you!